# NPM keeps giving me a version with incorrect files (angular2-localstorage)

Tags: npm, angular

I am using NodePackageManager and have a dependency to

```
"angular2-localstorage":"0.2.0"
```

My Problem is that i keep getting a wrong file.
I have no file **WebStorage.ts** in my node_modules folder.
But checking github https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localStorage shows, that it should be there.
(I have a file **LocalStorage.ts** instead - think its part of an older version)

I am quite new to Node and NodePackageManager - am i doing something wrong or missing something? Already tried cleaning node cache but that did not make a difference.